# Verbs which are always followed by past participle

Tags: linking-verbs, predicative-complement

- You seem unconcerned.
- The sauce tastes burned.

In these two sentences, past participle of verbs, **unconcerned** and **burned**, have been used after two especial verbs, ***seem*** and ***tastes***. Are they always followed by past participle? If they are not always followed by past participle, please say when they will be followed and when they will not be followed.

It would be helpful for me if I got a list that includes the list of verbs, which are always followed by past participle of verbs.

Comment: Do you mean past participle as opposed to adjectives, as opposed to present participle, or what?

Comment: When verbs '_have_' and '_get_' are used in a causative sense they may be followed by a past participle in the following pattern: _get/have + object + past participle_. Examples: _to get your house painted_ or _to have your hair cut_. Causative _make_ can also followed by a past participle: _to make oneself understood_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have spotted a certain class of English verbs called ***copular*** or linking verbs.  They link the subject to a predicate complement, either an equivalent noun (called a *predicate nominative*)

> John **is** my *son*.

or a descriptive modifier (called a *predicate adjective* in case the modifier is an adjective).

> John **is** *strong*.

As you've noted, the predicate modifier might well be a participle, which is just a verb form that finds service in a sentence in a role other than a verb.  The fact that the modifier is a participle is not significant.  The syntactic structure is the same for all modifiers:

> The sauce **tastes** *burned*.
>   The sauce **tastes** *delicious*.

Copular verbs are verbs of being, seeming, sensing, and a few others.  Copular verbs stand in contrast to dynamic verbs, which carry an **action** to an *object*:

> John **hit** my *son*.

This differs form the copular sentence, which makes *John* and *son* equivalent.  Here the verb carries out an action to *son*.  Dynamic verbs cannot govern following noun modifiers like adjectives.  You cannot say

> *John hit strong.

The following modifiers of dynamic verbs modify the verb, and so must be adverbs:

> John hit strongly.

Comment: Linking verbs are not always past participle. Ex: "We *are* the champions."

Comment: Assuming you mean that past participles aren't always the complements of linking verbs, yes.  That's why I mentioned predicate nominatives (like "champions") and said that the "fact that the modifier is a participle is not significant."

Comment: Great to see your answer here.

Answer (score -1):

1)**PASSIVE VOICE** IS PRODUCED WITH THE COMBINATION OF A FORM OF "TO BE" (or "get" - not that common) + A PAST PARTICIPLE.ex   That highway  WILL BE REPAIRED.
2)**PERFECT TENSES** USE HAVE/HAS or HAD + PAST PARTICIPLES. ex. THEY HAVE already FINISHED  the exam.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Can you [edit] to get rid of the all caps (also known as "shouting")?